# Entity Framework Core saves multiple records when inserting one record to a table

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working with ASP.NET Core 3.1. I'm saving data in a SQL Server table with this code, however it saves two records at the same time with sequential id. I don't understand what my mistake is. I appreciate of any help.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit(int id, APIApplicantViewModel apiapplicantviewmodel)
{
    var applicantQuery = //my query
    var apiQuery = //my query
    var gateQuery = //my query
    var laststatusQuery = //my query

    ShortApiApplicantJsonTO apiApplicantJson;

    var lastchangesDate = PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd").PersianToEnglish();

    ViewData["unconfirmedReason"] = new SelectList(_context.EntityType.Where(g => g.EntityKey == "unconfirmedReason"), "Id", "Name");
            
    // Insert
    if (apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.Id == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Set<Apiapplicant>().Add(new Apiapplicant
                    {
                        Apiid = apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.Apiid,
                        GateId = apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.GateId,
                        ApplicantId = apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.ApplicantId,
                        ApiRequestDate = apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.ApiRequestDate,
                        ApiRequestNo = apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.ApiRequestNo,
                        NocRequestDate = apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.NocRequestDate,
                        NocRequestNo = apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.NocRequestNo,
                        Url = apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.Url,
                        Description = apiapplicantviewmodel.apiApplicantvm.Description,
                        IsDeleted = false
                    });

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you call `AddOrEdit`?

Comment: try removing   
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
i think EF automatically save to the database when the transaction is finished. 

if u wannt to commit the changes manually ,try to implement the unit of work pattern